# Handling imports in externally-called multi-file script

Tags: python

I have a file structure like the following:

- *config.py*
- *main.py*
- *some_other_file.py*

where *config.py* contains easily accessible parameters but not much code otherwise. These should be accessible to all other code files. Normally `import config` would do, but in this case the python script is called externally from another program, and therefore the root calling directory is not the same as the one the files are located at (so just an `import` results in an exception since it does not find the files).

Right now, the solution I have is to include into my *main.py* file (the one that is directly called by the third program) the following:

```
code_path = "Path\\To\\My\\Project\\"
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, code_path)

import config
import some_other_file

...
```

However, this means having to modify *main.py* every time the code is moved around. I could live with that, but I would certainly like having one single, simple file with all necessary configuration, not needing to dig through the others (especially since the code may later be passed onto others who just want it to work as effortlessly as possible).

I tried having the `sys.path.insert` inside the config file, and having that be the file directly called by the external script (and all other files called from there). However, I run into the problem that when the other files do `import config`, it results in an import loop since they are also being imported from *config.py*. Typically, I believe this is solved by making the imports in the *config.py* file only once through something like `if __name__ == "__main__":` (see below). This does not work in my case, and the script never goes into the `if` statement, possibly because it is being called as a sub-routine by a third program and it is not the main program itself. As a result, **I have no way of enforcing a portion of the code in *config.py* to only be executed once.**

This is what I meant above for *config.py* (which does not work for my case):

```
...  # Some parameter definitions

if __name__ == "__main__":
  code_path = "Path\\To\\My\\Project\\"
  import sys
  sys.path.insert(0, code_path)

  import main  # Everything is then executed in main.py (where config.py is also cross-imported)
```

Is there any way to enforce the portion of code inside the `if` above to only be executed once even if cross-imported, but without relying on `__name__ == "__main__"`? Or any other way to handle this at all, while keeping all parameters and configuration data within one single, simple file.

By the way, I am using IronPython for this (not exactly a choice), but since I am sticking to hopefully very simple stuff, I believe it is common to all python versions.

tl;dr: I want a *config.py* file with a bunch of parameters, including the directory where the program is located, to be accessible to multiple .py files. I want to avoid needing the project directory written in the "main" code file, since that should be a parameter and therefore **only** in *config.py*. The whole thing is passed to and executed by a third external program, so the directory where these files are located is not the same as where they are called from (therefore the project directory has to be included to system path at some point to import the different files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible design alternative that is fairly common would be to rely on environment variables configured with a single file. Your multi-program system would then be started with some run script and your python application would then need to use something along the lines of os.env[…] to get/set/check the needed variables. Your directory would then look something along the lines of:

```
.
.
.
.env (environment variables - doesn't have to be called .env)
main.py
run.sh (starts system of programs - doesn't have to be called run.sh)
.
.
.
```

For the run script, you could then "activate" the environment variables and, after, start the relevant programs. If using bash as your terminal:

```
source .env # "activate" your environment variables

# Then the command to start whatever you need to; for example
#
# python main.py
# or
# ./myprogram
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Isn't there a way around this using only python? Some way to ensure certain lines (imports) are only executed once even if the script containing them is cross-imported later, but without relying on ```if __name__ == "__main__"```. It is not just me trying to avoid bash scripts (which it is, too), but the main program has an IronPython interpreter bundled with it, so it handles all the python execution internally, and I'm not sure environment variables are available. If there is no other workaround, I'll give that a try and accept your answer.

Comment: @Arce11 Thanks for the follow up. Python imports are executed once and then cached. Importing the same module at a later time references what is in the cache, so you shouldn't need to manually check and prevent repeated imports.

Comment: Alright! I have just tested it, you are very much right. I guess I can run *config.py* with the script directory as a variable in it, from there import *main.py*, and even if *main.py* imports back *config.py*, it will not loop around the imports. Thank you very much!